# Errors when using Sqlite in UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I am using Visual Studio 16.8. and I am trying to make an UWP application working with EntityFramework and Sqlite.

I started initially with a WPF app, but I decided to abandon and move to UWP mostly because there are more controls supported (AutoSuggestBox).

I am following the documentation steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio, but I get errors at every step:

1. Installing the package

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`

> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.3 is not compatible with uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.3 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
> Why do I get an error message about netstandard??? Shouldn't EntityFrameworkCore be compiled with .NET Core?
> 2. After some research, it seems that I need to install the 1.0.0 version of these package. After installing both EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, I create a ApplicationContext with a model and I want to add a migration:

`Add-Migration First`

I get another error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Checking my PC, I have the correct System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll in several location:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions\4.0.0\lib\DNXCore50
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions\4.0.0\lib\net46
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions\4.0.0\lib\netcore50
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions\4.0.0\lib\dotnet
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions\4.0.0\lib\net46

However, I see that on compilation, the DLL is only searched in 2 locations:

- %HOME%/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/1.0.0/tools/net451/
- $(ProjectDir)bin/x86/Debug/

The most annoying thing is that ~3 months ago I did the same exact steps and everything (step 2) worked flawlessly, yet now I am struggling with basic things.

---

Edit: After some digging with procmon, it seems that the working project is compiled with netstandard1.3 and MSBuild, while the one not working is compiled with microsoft.netcore.universalplatform\6.2.10.

Comment: use the 3.1 versions where latest version is 3.1.12

Comment: @magicandre1981 I created a clean UWP app, added both Packages with version 3.1.12, I get "Startup project 'MealPlanUwp' is a Universal Windows Platform app. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support this type of project. For more information on using the EF Core Tools with UWP projects"

Comment: ok, looks like EF Core doesn't support UWP. Use a HTTP middleware to send/get data and on the service access the database

Comment: @magicandre1981 it seems that for some people it is working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7Fv0mRqe7g

Comment: ok, so change targetframework to .net standard 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering Target Version to Windows 10, 1803 and Min version to 15063